# How do you convert the SQL `to_date(date) - INTERVAL '1 MONTH'` to JOOQ's DSL API?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

[JOOQ's Date docs](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.4/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/datetime-functions/) contain the usual date functions (`to_date`, `dateadd`, ect..). However, I couldn't find any docs explaining how to use SQL's INTERVAL type to perform date math.

Can this SQL be represented in JOOQ or is my only option to dip down into raw SQL?

```
to_date(my_date_col) - INTERVAL '1 MONTH'
```

Comment: Checkout this https://blog.jooq.org/tag/datetime-arithmetic/

Comment: Why are you calling `to_date()` with a column that is already a date? That makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use any of these

```java
TABLE.MY_DATE_COL.minus(new YearToMonth(0, 1));
DSL.dateSub(TABLE.MY_DATE_COL, new YearToMonth(0, 1));
DSL.dateSub(TABLE.MY_DATE_COL, 1, DatePart.MONTH);
```